# SQL Server script for SQLite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-insert

I need to convert scripts for SQL Server, so I can use them for SQLite.

The scripts look like this:

```
DECLARE @var1 int = (SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE id = 'val1')
DECLARE @var2 int  = (SELECT Id FROM Table2 WHERE id = 'val2')

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE id_1 = @var1 and id_2 = @var2)
    INSERT INTO Table3(id_1, id_2) VALUES (@var1, @var2)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table4 WHERE id ='val3')
    INSERT INTO Table4(id, desc) values ('111', 'new entry')
GO
```

What is the best practice for executing these scripts in SQLite?

Comment: *"What is the best practise for executing these scripts in SQLite?"* By translating each one to SQLite's dialect.

Comment: Improve the queries before converting them. There's no reason to store IDs into variables just to insert them into another table, or use `NOT EXISTS` to check if the values exist or not. `INSERT ...SELECT ..FROM ... WHERE` can be used to create just one query that inserts the results of a SELECT query to a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support variables.

You can use a CTE that returns the values of the 2 variables as columns:

```
WITH cte(var1, var2) AS (
  SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE id = 'val1'), (SELECT Id FROM Table2 WHERE id = 'val2') 
)
INSERT INTO Table3(id_1, id_2) 
SELECT var1, var2
FROM cte 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table3 t3 INNER JOIN cte c ON t3.id_1 = c.var1 AND t3.id_2 = c.var2);

INSERT INTO Table4(id, `desc`) 
SELECT '111', 'new entry'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table4 WHERE id ='val3')
```